# Boosting recommendation results in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, union, social-networking, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to implement a **recommendation algorithm** using **Neo4j**, which is similar to the implementation on this [page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-boostingrecommendations.html).

Right now I have a simple social example in which a **User** can:

- **follow** another user
- **play** a game
- **live** in a country

The idea is to make a friend suggestion algorithm based on whether other users are friends of friends, play the same game, live in the same country and/or follow the user in question.

With the exception of the latter, it would be quite easy implement using the example in the page above like this:

```
MATCH (origin)-[r1:FOLLOWS|PLAYS|LIVES_IN]-(c)-[r2:FOLLOWS|PLAYS|LIVES_IN]-(candidate)
WHERE type(r1)=type(r2) AND NOT (source)-[:FOLLOWS]->(candidate)  
RETURN candidate, SUM(ROUND(r2.weight) AS boost
ORDER BY boost DESC LIMIT 10
```

However, the only feasible way to do the whole thing at once would be to do a union with another query and processing the result. Something along these lines:

```
THE_QUERY_ABOVE

UNION

MATCH (origin)<-[r:FOLLOWS]-(candidate)
RETURN candidate, r.weight as boost

WITH candidate, boost
RETURN DISTINCT candidate, SUM(boost)
ORDER BY boost DESC LIMIT 10
```

But as far as I know, post-processing a `UNION` result is not possible with Cypher yet...

Therefore, my question is: **is this possible to achieve in a single query? and how?**

And if it is, **is there a possible solution in which I don't have to specify the weight in the relations in order to avoid having to change all the relations when I want to change the priorities?**

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (origin)-[r1:FOLLOWS|PLAYS|LIVES_IN]-(c)-[r2:FOLLOWS|PLAYS|LIVES_IN]-(candidate)
WHERE type(r1)=type(r2) AND NOT (origin)-[:FOLLOWS]->(candidate)
WITH origin,candidate,(
  CASE
  WHEN candidate IS NOT NULL THEN [{ candidate: candidate, boost: SUM(ROUND(r2.weight))}]
  ELSE NULL END ) AS res1
OPTIONAL MATCH (candidate)-[r3:FOLLOWS]->(origin)
WITH (
  CASE
  WHEN candidate IS NOT NULL THEN [{ candidate: candidate, boost: SUM(ROUND(r3.weight))}]
  ELSE NULL END )+ res1 AS res2
UNWIND res2 AS result
RETURN result.candidate AS candidate, SUM(result.boost) AS boost
ORDER BY boost DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Does this work for you? *If this does not work, can you [share a console](http://console.neo4j.org/) with sample data?*

It uses 2 `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses that share the same `origin` and `candidate` nodes. Each `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause takes care of one of your `OR` cases, putting the results for that case in a map collection (or `NULL`, if the match failed). Near the end, the collections (which contain maps with the same structure) are combined and unwound as individual rows. Finally, the rows with the same `candidate` values have their `boost` values summed, and the top 10 results (by boost value) are returned.

Comment: Hi @cybersam. Thanks for the quick reply. However, the solution you provided isn't quite what I'm looking for. That will only find candidates that follow the origin AND all the other stuff... What I'm looking for is an OR, meaning that I want that any user who might follow the origin to boost his recommendation score.

Comment: Nearly there @cybersam... But I also want to return the users that **only** follow the origin and nothing else... The way you did it only returns those users if they are matched as candidates in the first `optional match`... I tried to change the 2nd `candidate` to `candidate2` but it's returning some weird results... I can share a console with you if you prefer...

Comment: A console would help.

Comment: Here's the [console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/at4oa9) @cybersam. The results should be *(Agent Smith:20,Cypher:14,Niobe:11,The Architect:10)* but is *(Agent Smith:50,The Architect:30,Cypher:28,Niobe:22)* instead... My suspicion is that the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` is generating duplicate boost or something... Anyway, in your current solution, the results are correct but thy are missing the users that only follow the origin (in this case, The Architect)

Answer (score 0):

You could use "optional Match"

Comment: Hi @Mvde. That's also not a perfect fit for this use case, since the optional match still requires some other match to happen. What I'm trying to do is something like an *OPTIONAL MATCH* for EVERY path... but it would still be tough to link both matches together

Comment: you could use Match(origin) optional match(origin)-[]->() and so on or am i wrong?

Comment: It's not that simple @Mvde. The challenge here is to aggregate results of different `OPTIONAL MATCH` paths, as you can see in @cybersam 's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33087863/2194665)